# clicking on emacs blows away x selection

Tags: emacs, mouse, clipboard, drag, gnome

Much of the time when I use the mouse to click on an emacs window, the x selection which I hope to paste into the buffer is blown away. This seems to be caused by the slight shift of the hand as I apply the left click causing an inadvertant "drag copy."  I do not believe I will be able to break this particular habit.

One solution I have found to prevent this is to set:

```
(setq mouse-drag-copy-region nil)
```

however this has the unfortunate side effect of preventing me from using the mouse drag functionality at all in emacs.  Is there a way to control mouse drag behavior so that a click is ignored unless it spands two or more characters within the buffer?

I am coding on Centos 5.x + GNOME 2 with GNU emacs 23.3.1 in case it makes a difference.

This appears to be a GTK/X issue; I can produce similar behavior with other apps.

Comment: Have you tried not using your .emacs?  i.e. can you reproduce the behavior when you start Emacs with the '-q' option?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I can observe the behavior even with -q.  Also, through experimenttaion I discovered that it is in part the (natural) movement of my hand when I make that initial click on the screen that is blowing away the copied text (the question is updated accordingly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in emacs that was introduced into the source code history in 2001.  I have posted a patch that can be applied to local installations.  Hopefully the emacs maintainers will investigate further.

Here is my patch and discussion:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2011-08/msg00818.html

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to this is to modify the function `mouse-drag-track`, which can be found in `mouse.el`.  To find the function definition, <kbd>M-x find-function mouse-drag-track RET</kbd>.

Copy that into your .emacs file and make one small change.  Find the `and` statement that looks like:

```
(and mouse-drag-copy-region
     do-mouse-drag-region-post-process
     (let (deactivate-mark)
       (copy-region-as-kill region-commencement
                            region-termination)))
```

And modify it to have the check to ensure the region is at least 2 characters.  I've made this check to be 10 characters for easier testing:

```
(and mouse-drag-copy-region
     (>= (abs (- region-commencement region-termination)) 10) ;; THIS IS NEW
     do-mouse-drag-region-post-process
     (let (deactivate-mark)
       (copy-region-as-kill region-commencement
                            region-termination)))
```

I don't see a clean way to do this via advice or hooks or variable settings.
Be sure to have a `(require 'mouse)` before your definition of `mouse-drag-track` to ensure you override the built-in definition, as opposed to it overriding yours.  You also might want to add a check to your .emacs right above the re-definition to remind you to check for new versions of the library/function you're overwriting:

```
(unless (eq emacs-major-version 23)
  (error "check for new mouse-drag-track"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  After instrumenting your solution, I have determined that mouse-drag-track is not the appropriate entry point.  I have created a bug: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2011-07/msg02003.html.  Basically, I nolonger think it is my unsteady hands that are the problem but rather emacs behavior in an X window environment.